# Combining map and reduce

Tags: python, reduce, python-itertools

I want to find a neat way to achieve the following:

Pretend I have a list:

```
> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And a simple function that just adds two numbers:

```
> def add(a, b)
      return a+b
```

I can reduce the list `x` directly with:

```
> sum = reduce(add, x)
> print(sum)
15
```

Which gives me the sum just fine. But I would like to know the value after **each application of add**. So using a function similar to reduce, I'd like to get back the following array:

```
> result = SOME_FUNCTION(add, x)
> print(result)
[3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Does anybody have a cool way of achieving that. I have a strong preference for using some form of itertools solution if possible :)

Comment: Have you looked at `itertools` functions? One of them does exactly this.

Comment: This is called a *cumulative sum*. Try `np.cumsum(x)` for instance. Probably a dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009019/python-recursive-sum-list

Comment: Well, sum is just a pathological example :P I'm trying to achieve this with a very different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want itertools

```
from itertools import accumulate
list(accumulate(x))
Out [130]:
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Alternatively a generator loop

```
def cumsum(x):
    total = 0
    for x in it:
        total += x
        yield total
list(cumsum(x))
Out [129]:
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Or simply as David mentioned:

```
np.cumsum(x)
Out [123]:
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: You can use `list(islice(accumlate(x), 1, None))` to meet the OP's expected output

Comment: I don't know how I managed to miss accumulate. But this is exactly what I needed :P Bravo! and thank-you!!!

Comment: glad that helped :)